# Why is adding element.getAttribute() here making my php script return error 500?

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

This is the code i'm using to parse a remote XML:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xml");

$x = $xmlDoc->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item)
{
    if($item->nodeName == 'Body')
        foreach ($item->childNodes AS $body_item)
        {
            if($body_item->nodeName == 'Cube')
                foreach ($body_item->childNodes AS $cube_item)
                {                                                   
                    print " - ".$cube_item->nodeName . " : ".$cube_item->getAttribute("currency")." = ". $cube_item->nodeValue . "<br>";

                }


        }
}
```

If i remove the getAttribute part the script runs smoothly, but adding it causes it to return error 500.

The xml is available at the address if you want to check it out or something.

Once I activated error reporting I found the error to be: `Object of class DOMText could not be converted to string`

Comment: `500` means "Read the server logs to find out that the error is".

Comment: @Quentin I know, i'm just hoping i'm doing something stupid and obvious since I don't often parse XML

Comment: It would be easier to tell if you looked in the server logs and told us what the error was

Comment: Edited with the error i got from error reporting mode.

Comment: My crystal ball says that your fatal error is; cannot call `getAttribute()` on a non-object :)

Comment: @Jack Actually `call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()`  I like it when the full URL to an XML file is supplied in the question. Makes for easy console verification.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Which explains why your answer was out so fast :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `childNodes` is supplying both regular and text nodes.  You can only call `getAttribute()` on the regular Element nodes (type 1).  Check first that they are not text nodes before executing your `print`:

```
foreach ($body_item->childNodes AS $cube_item)
{
   // Only attempt to print the regular DOM elements                          
   if ($cube_item->nodeType == 1)
   {
     print " - ".$cube_item->nodeName . " : ".$cube_item->getAttribute("currency")." = ". $cube_item->nodeValue . "<br>";
   }
}
```

If in your `foreach` loop you were to check the `nodeType` of each of the `childNodes`, you would most likely see something similar to an alternating `3 1 3 1 3 1` for the whitespace text and regular element nodes, when you only really want the element nodes (`1`)

[MDN has a reference list of DOM node types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.nodeType).

Incidentally, a quick verification of the fix with your full code produces:

```
 - Rate : AED = 0.9514<br>
 - Rate : AUD = 3.6518<br>
 - Rate : BGN = 2.3169<br>
 - Rate : BRL = 1.6787<br>
 - Rate : CAD = 3.5182<br>
 - Rate : CHF = 3.7628<br>
 - Rate : CNY = 0.5613<br>
 - Rate : CZK = 0.1790<br>
 - Rate : DKK = 0.6076<br>
 - Rate : EGP = 0.5726<br>
 - Rate : EUR = 4.5313<br>
 - Rate : GBP = 5.5990<br>
 - Rate : HUF = 1.6075<br>
 - Rate : INR = 0.0627<br>
 - Rate : JPY = 4.2601<br>
 - Rate : KRW = 0.3217<br>
 - Rate : MDL = 0.2836<br>
 - Rate : MXN = 0.2692<br>
 - Rate : NOK = 0.6169<br>
 - Rate : NZD = 2.8782<br>
 - Rate : PLN = 1.1019<br>
 - Rate : RSD = 0.0405<br>
 - Rate : RUB = 0.1127<br>
 - Rate : SEK = 0.5268<br>
 - Rate : TRY = 1.9469<br>
 - Rate : UAH = 0.4288<br>
 - Rate : USD = 3.4950<br>
 - Rate : XAU = 196.3192<br>
 - Rate : XDR = 5.3606<br>
 - Rate : ZAR = 0.3937<br>
```